# Will replacing mongrel with Thin or Passenger improve scalability

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to improve the scalability of my Rails app. Currently it runs on a apache/mongrel (mongrel cluster actually).

Will replacing this with Thin or Passenger improve the scalability of my app?

Thanks,
Sivakumar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

The overhead in your app is almost guaranteed to be in your app itself, and not in the relatively lightweight hosting container.

As always:

Test. Measure.

You can only address specific issues.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a good link [benchmark of mongrel, thin and passenger](http://izumi.plan99.net/blog/index.php/2008/03/31/benchmark-passenger-mod_rails-vs-mongrel-vs-thin/)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can a single mongrel instance serve only one request at a time?